# Keeping LaTeX contents in line with non-latex text

Tags: latex

I am using LaTex from the JetPack plugin, which is similar but not identical to TeX for maths, for my WordPress blog where I post course work. How do I get the generated formulae to centre on the line so the equals sign lines up with the normal text that I have typed? to see what I mean please check [this blog entry.](http://www.codejourneys.net/openuni/tu100-my-digital-life-block-2-part-5-session-1-3-using-numbers-to-cope-counts-activity-3/)

here are a the two offending pieces of LaTeX for the last two equations of the equations:

```
$latex = \large{\dfrac{1}{62,000}} $
```

and

```
\left(\large{\dfrac{10,000}{62,000,000}}\right) 100\% $
```

thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't used that plugin, so I can't speak to whether there are any configurations that would help. However, I think your issue could be solved with a simple css rule:

```
img.latex {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

would center all your LaTeX-generated images on the line they fall on.

Comment: A quick test in the Chrome debugger confirms that this would do the trick.

Comment: Added it as a custom css part inside the theme options, works like a charm, thank you so very much for such a quick, simple answer :)